# About Dockerfile "FROM"

Tags: python, docker

I am confused with docker about `FROM`. I have 2 different codes which one is the best code? Or do you have a better code?

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-mono:latest
WORKDIR /data
RUN apk update --no-cache -U && apk add --no-cache python3
```

and

```
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine as python
WORKDIR /data
RUN apk update --no-cache -U

FROM frolvlad/alpine-mono:latest
WORKDIR /data
COPY from=python . .
```

The second code above not only uses `apk add --no-cache python3` but it uses additional code. But still better using the first code?

Comment: We really can't tell you which is "best" since we have no idea what you're trying to do. Your second example shows a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), which is useful in many situations, but your two examples here don't appear to be trying to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Are you referring to the `as` part of the `FROM` statement in the second example as the difference? If so, it serves a unique purpose, and is generally used for multistage builds. So one isn't necessarily better than the other. Rather, one is *required in certain circumstances compared to the other*.

Answer (score 2):

The first example is the standard scenario: you start with a base and just add layers to it.

The second example uses the FROM ... AS ... form. Essentially the third 3 lines ("FROM base" onwards) are a continuation of the first 3 lines - you could swap the first two groups and rewrite as:

```
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine as python
WORKDIR /data
RUN apk update --no-cache -U

FROM frolvlad/alpine-mono:latest
WORKDIR /data
RUN apk update --no-cache -U
COPY --from=python . .
```

or something like that (not totally clear about the COPY). This will pull python:3.9.6-alpine and do an update (most people advise not to do a full update but I will ignore that view as out-of-scope of the question). It will then get hold of a new base and then copy the required directory from one image to the other.

The FROM ... AS ... coupled with COPY --from (AKA multi-stage build process) allows you to do a few things:

- Build something in a docker environment and then copy the generated product over - done properly, any files used during the build process are completely forgotten and not in the docker image layers
- Grab a file or directory out of an existing environment

The latter is I guess being used here but you have to be careful that the environments are compatible. Others may disagree, but that looks like overkill to me.

Comment: So is better install it with `apk add --no-cache python3` or use two base image?

Comment: I would just install.
The second pattern is best suited if you somehow need to install something else that is not needed in the eventual product - e.g.  if you have to compile something, you can install the compiler in one image and then just copy the eventual binary that you build. If you do that, you need to ensure that both images are fully compatible (using the same parent makes live simpler),